# What theorem allow us to say formally that certain properties in complex plane are the same as properties in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

I have read many proofs that are related to the complex numbers and many of them says something as "taking the theorem for the $\mathbb{R}^2$ case, we can follow that..." but I have never seen a theorem that makes available to us to make such analogies. I admit that is intuitive clear, since $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ are the same in a certain way, but I'm looking for formal reasoning.

Does anybody know something about the existence of such a theorem?

Comment: The main general facts are that both $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{C}$ have the same underlying set, the same norm, thus the same metric and the same topology. Perhaps you can give an example of a proof in complex analysis which appeals to "the $\mathbb{R}^2$ case" in a puzzling way.

Comment: It's not so much a theorem as a definition.  Geometrically and topologically $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb C$ are defined to be identical.  Algebraically $\mathbb C$ is defined to be $\mathbb R^2$ with a multiplication (which is undefined on $\mathbb R^2$) defined as (a,b)(x,y) = (ax - by, bx + ya).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **set** R^2 when equipped with addition becomes the abelian group (R^2:+).
That abelian group, when equipped with complex multiplication becomes the field (R^2 + :x) called the Field of Complex Numbers.
For spatial (geometric) properties, more operators may be imposed on the set R^2.
One needs to be clear about the distinction between  a **set** , and the mathematical systems created from  a set.